# How to find average of counts using Excel Pivots

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Hello Everyone i have the following table for which i need to find the average count of 'Names' per month. This is how may data looks

```
CheckinDate Name    Month
1/1/2017    asdsad  January
1/2/2017    sdsf    January
1/3/2017    sdfsdf  January
1/3/2017    fsffdf  January
1/2/2017    sdsf    January
1/1/2017    asdsad  January
1/2/2017    sdsf    January
2/1/2017    asdsad  February
2/1/2017    sdsf    February
2/1/2017    sdfsdf  February
2/1/2017    fsffdf  February
2/2/2017    sdsf    February
2/2/2017    asdsad  February
2/2/2017    sdsf    February
2/2/2017    asdsad  February
2/2/2017    fsffdf  February
```

What I am expecting as the pivot table is like this. For January i want to show there are total 7 checkins divided by 31 days

```
Month      AverageCheckinsPerDay    
January    0.225806452                 
February   0.321428571
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Why even bother with a Pivot?  You could just do a COUNTIF of the month column divided by DAY(EOMONTH(your_date,0)) where your date is some day within that month (Jan 1, etct).

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest to do outside the PivotTable (ie Count entries per month, then divide count by days for the month in question) however is possible within a PT provided the days in the month are supplied. For example add a column with `1/days in month in question` for each row and then sum that column in the PT (with `Month` for ROWS).